# cakephp Image escape false not working

Tags: html, cakephp

I am making a Image link to user profile, but it is not working as it should be 
this is my code.with this i want to add contoroller,function and id. How i can do it.

```
<?php 
    $pic = $User['User']['url'];
    if(!$pic){
     echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('pro.jpg'), array('alt'=>$User['User']['handle'],'title' => $User['User']['handle']),array('escape'=>false) ,array('class'=>'inner_image'));
}else{

    echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image($User['User']['url']),array('alt' => $User['User']['handle']),array('escape'=>false),array('class'=>'inner_image'));
}   
?>
```

This code is making image a link but i can't define a link and it is not accepting the class 
.I want to pass this url

```
$this->Html->link('', array('controller'=>'User','action'=>'view','id'=>$User['User']['id']));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What cake version are you using? You don't seem to be following the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3alink) for `Html::link`.

> HtmlHelper::link(string $title, mixed $url = null, array $options =
>   array(), string $confirmMessage = false)

`alt`, `escape` and `class` should be indexes in the `options` array, but you're not defininf the `url` parameter anywhere.

It should be something like this

```
if(!$pic){
  echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('pro.jpg'), $url_array,  array('alt'=>$User['User']['handle'],'title' => $User['User']['handle'],'escape'=>false,'class'=>'inner_image'));
} else {
    echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image($User['User']['url']), $url_array, array('alt' => $User['User']['handle'], 'escape'=>false, 'class'=>'inner_image'));
```

(don't know what url you want to point this at, so replace `$url_array` to your convenience.

Comment: I am using cake 2.3.8

Comment: Good, the doc I linked is for 2.x versions

Comment: if your using `Html::link`, then the class is associated to the link, not the image. you want to add a class to the image? your question is not very clear if so.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image($pic, array('class'=>'inner_image')), $url_array, array('alt' => $User['User']['handle'], 'escape'=>false));
```